# Virtual box in Vmware Player

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox, vmware, virtualization

I run virtual box indtalled on ubuntu 14.04 x64 that run in Vmware Player (3Core, Virtualization, 8gb RAM) with guest os ubuntu 14.04 x64 (1Core, Virtualization, 1gb RAM, 80Mb Video).

And it's very laggy drawing and in little window, how can i cure it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once ran (I kid you not) MVS, within the Hercules mainframe emulator, running on Linux within VMWare on a Windows box, and it was also slow.

Maybe you might think about *removing* some of those emulation layers since each of them adds a cost.

For example, run whatever you want to run in the lowest-level VirtualBox either on a VirtualBox installed directly on your top-level hardware, or ditch VirtualBox and just run your thing within VMWare itself.

Or, to satisfy the VirtualBox zealots, ditch VMWare instead and run everything in VirtualBox VMs at the top level.

Comment: I know virtual box have guest extensions (some drivers how i know), it's laggy, and i can't check up installed them or not.

Comment: I install guest extensions, it's more faster, but not enough. icheck rpd work.